# Change CircleAvatar size in ListTile

Tags: flutter, listview, user-interface, mobile

I want to increase the size of an CircleAvatar as Leading of a Listtile. But if i increase the Radius the Circle doesnt keep its ratio and becomes an ellipse.

Here is my Code:

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: friendlist.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
print(friendlist[index]);
return ListTile(
        title: Text(friendlist[index]["nickname"],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 50,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(core.url + "profiles/" + friendlist[index]["avatar_id"]),
          ),
        subtitle:
        Text(friendlist[index]["lost_last"])
    );
}));
```

What I tried:

1. Nesting the Circle Avatar into a Container with fixed Width and Height -> Circle is still an ellipse
2. Changing the ItemExtent of the ListView.builder -> The Circle still cant use all of the empty space and becomes an ellipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible with ListTitle, as this is the applied restrictions they have added for the standard of the widget

> To be accessible, tappable leading and trailing widgets have to be at
> least 48x48 in size. However, to adhere to the Material spec, trailing
> and leading widgets in one-line ListTiles should visually be at most
> 32 (dense: true) or 40 (dense: false) in height, which may conflict
> with the accessibility requirement.

You can create custom widget for your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to change the `CircleAvatar` actually , There are two properties related to size: `minRadius` and `maxRadius`. The are used to set the minimum and maximum radius respectively. If you already use radius, you are not allowed to use minRadius and/or maxRadius. On the contrary, if either minRadius or maxRadius is set, you are not allowed to use radius :

```
CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://www.woolha.com/media/2020/03/eevee.png'),
    minRadius: 50,
    maxRadius: 75,
  )
```